# Which Pokemon have the highest CP cap?

Tags: pokemon-go

It's clear that the evolved form of Pokemon have a far higher CP cap (and it looks like minimum too) but it would also seem there is a difference between different Pokemon.

For example I have an Oddish at 184 CP which is at 50% of it's cap, and I also have a Ratata at 185 CP but it is far closer to its cap, around 90%.

Which Pokemon have the highest CP caps?

Comment: It is also worth noting that CP cap is level related

Comment: @Timelord64 as Dylan said CP cap is related to level, so people with higher levels will be able to screenshot higher level pokemon. My question was asking which pokemon have higher cp than others.

Comment: @Aequitas I suppose they all have different formulas for min and max, which is a function of their level. And the actual power is just determined by the percentage full the bar is (it sounds like you may understand this). I don't think there's very much data that's been mined in the way of figuring this out, but I assure you in about a week's time you'll be able to find all that information on a wiki somewhere

Comment: @Aequitas I'm also unsure if this game has IV/EV like other pokemon games, and if some pokemon caught of the same type would actually have higher caps.

Comment: So far out of all my pokemon it looks like rapidash would have the highest, I have a ponyta with a cap of around 700, so after it's evolved it looks like it will be far higher than anything else I have so far. But then again maybe when I evolve it, the cap doesn't increase that much

Comment: It is all trainer level based. I started off catching 10 - 20 CP ratatas, now at level 12 I catch them at 120+, everytime I evolved a higher level ratata is was higher than previous and wild caught raticates. This means just keep catching (candies+xp), evolving(+500xp) and transfering(candies+xp?). Use the highest level pokemon that you have to fight and take gyms while moving up on other pokemon to (re)take gyms. It is also all random CP (min/max) still get the occasional low level ratata

Comment: @kiwi yes for the same pokemon, but a max powered up ratata is going to be less than a max powered up ponyta for instance

Answer (score 15):

## Table below in "Max Total CP" order.

*(I included the table below so there is no need to jump to a new link, or incase the original is inaccessible.)*

As you do powerups after finding a wild Pokemon, some multiple better, thus being stronger or top tier pokemon.

Multiple **your character level** by **CP per Powerup** (aka, multiplier)  to see *approximately* how much **their CP would go up**.

**Ndex** is their Pokédex number

```
| Ndex | Pokémon    | Max Total CP | Min CP/Lvl | Avg CP/Lvl | Max CP/Lvl | CP Multip/Evo | HP Base Stat | Max Total HP |
|------|------------|--------------|------------|------------|------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
| 150  | Mewtwo     | 4144         | 53.4       | 56.8       | 60.3       |               | 106          | 179          |
| 149  | Dragonite  | 3500         | 44.6       | 47.7       | 50.9       | 2.1           | 91           | 155          |
| 151  | Mew        | 3299         | 41.9       | 44.9       | 48         |               | 100          | 169          |
| 146  | Moltres    | 3240         | 41.1       | 44.1       | 47.2       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 145  | Zapdos     | 3114         | 39.4       | 42.3       | 45.3       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 143  | Snorlax    | 3112         | 39.3       | 42.2       | 45.3       |               | 160          | 264          |
| 59   | Arcanine   | 2983         | 37.6       | 40.5       | 43.4       | 2.3           | 90           | 154          |
| 131  | Lapras     | 2980         | 37.6       | 40.4       | 43.4       |               | 130          | 217          |
| 144  | Articuno   | 2978         | 37.6       | 40.4       | 43.3       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 103  | Exeggutor  | 2955         | 37.2       | 40.1       | 43         | 2.8           | 95           | 162          |
| 134  | Vaporeon   | 2816         | 35.3       | 38.1       | 41         | 2.7           | 130          | 217          |
| 130  | Gyarados   | 2688         | 33.7       | 36.4       | 39.1       | 12.1          | 95           | 162          |
| 136  | Flareon    | 2643         | 32.9       | 35.6       | 38.5       | 2.6           | 65           | 114          |
| 6    | Charizard  | 2602         | 32.5       | 35.1       | 37.9       | 1.7           | 78           | 135          |
| 89   | Muk        | 2602         | 32.5       | 35.1       | 37.9       | 2.1           | 105          | 177          |
| 80   | Slowbro    | 2597         | 32.4       | 35.1       | 37.8       | 2.2           | 95           | 162          |
| 68   | Machamp    | 2594         | 32.4       | 35         | 37.8       | 1.5           | 90           | 154          |
| 3    | Venusaur   | 2580         | 32.2       | 34.8       | 37.6       | 1.6           | 80           | 138          |
| 9    | Blastoise  | 2542         | 31.7       | 34.3       | 37         | 1.6           | 79           | 136          |
| 71   | Victreebel | 2530         | 31.5       | 34.1       | 36.8       | 1.5           | 80           | 138          |
| 62   | Poliwrath  | 2505         | 31.2       | 33.8       | 36.5       | 1.9           | 90           | 154          |
| 45   | Vileplume  | 2492         | 31         | 33.6       | 36.3       | 1.5           | 75           | 130          |
| 31   | Nidoqueen  | 2485         | 30.9       | 33.5       | 36.2       | 1.8           | 90           | 154          |
| 34   | Nidoking   | 2475         | 30.8       | 33.3       | 36         | 1.9           | 81           | 139          |
| 36   | Clefable   | 2397         | 29.8       | 32.3       | 34.9       | 2.1           | 95           | 162          |
| 55   | Golduck    | 2386         | 29.6       | 32.1       | 34.7       | 2.2           | 80           | 138          |
| 76   | Golem      | 2303         | 28.5       | 30.9       | 33.5       | 1.6           | 80           | 138          |
| 126  | Magmar     | 2265         | 27.9       | 30.4       | 33         |               | 65           | 114          |
| 110  | Weezing    | 2250         | 27.7       | 30.2       | 32.7       | 2             | 65           | 114          |
| 112  | Rhydon     | 2243         | 27.7       | 30.1       | 32.6       | 2             | 105          | 177          |
| 139  | Omastar    | 2233         | 27.5       | 30         | 32.5       | 2.1           | 70           | 122          |
| 73   | Tentacruel | 2220         | 27.4       | 29.8       | 32.3       | 2.6           | 80           | 138          |
| 78   | Rapidash   | 2199         | 27         | 29.5       | 32         | 1.5           | 65           | 114          |
| 38   | Ninetales  | 2188         | 26.9       | 29.3       | 31.8       | 2.8           | 73           | 127          |
| 97   | Hypno      | 2184         | 26.9       | 29.3       | 31.8       | 2.1           | 85           | 146          |
| 121  | Starmie    | 2182         | 26.8       | 29.2       | 31.8       | 2.4           | 60           | 106          |
| 40   | Wigglytuff | 2177         | 26.6       | 29.1       | 31.7       | 2.5           | 140          | 233          |
| 142  | Aerodactyl | 2165         | 26.6       | 29         | 31.5       |               | 80           | 138          |
| 87   | Dewgong    | 2145         | 26.4       | 28.7       | 31.2       | 2             | 90           | 154          |
| 135  | Jolteon    | 2140         | 26.2       | 28.6       | 31.1       | 2.1           | 65           | 114          |
| 141  | Kabutops   | 2130         | 26.1       | 28.5       | 31         | 2             | 60           | 106          |
| 127  | Pinsir     | 2121         | 26         | 28.4       | 30.9       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 125  | Electabuzz | 2119         | 26         | 28.3       | 30.8       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 18   | Pidgeot    | 2091         | 25.7       | 28         | 30.4       | 1.8           | 83           | 143          |
| 94   | Gengar     | 2078         | 25.4       | 27.8       | 30.2       | 1.5           | 60           | 106          |
| 123  | Scyther    | 2073         | 25.4       | 27.7       | 30.2       |               | 70           | 122          |
| 91   | Cloyster   | 2052         | 24.9       | 27.4       | 29.9       | 2.6           | 50           | 90           |
| 115  | Kangaskhan | 2043         | 25         | 27.3       | 29.7       |               | 105          | 177          |
| 119  | Seaking    | 2043         | 25         | 27.3       | 29.7       | 2.2           | 80           | 138          |
| 26   | Raichu     | 2028         | 24.7       | 27.1       | 29.5       | 2.4           | 60           | 106          |
| 42   | Golbat     | 1921         | 23.4       | 25.6       | 28         | 3.2           | 75           | 130          |
| 49   | Venomoth   | 1890         | 23         | 25.2       | 27.5       | 1.9           | 70           | 122          |
| 82   | Magneton   | 1879         | 22.7       | 25         | 27.4       | 2.2           | 50           | 90           |
| 57   | Primeape   | 1864         | 22.6       | 24.8       | 27.1       | 2.2           | 65           | 114          |
| 128  | Tauros     | 1844         | 22.4       | 24.5       | 26.8       |               | 75           | 130          |
| 85   | Dodrio     | 1836         | 22.2       | 24.4       | 26.7       | 2.2           | 60           | 106          |
| 99   | Kingler    | 1823         | 22         | 24.2       | 26.5       | 2.4           | 55           | 98           |
| 65   | Alakazam   | 1813         | 21.9       | 24.1       | 26.4       | 1.7           | 55           | 98           |
| 28   | Sandslash  | 1810         | 21.9       | 24.1       | 26.3       | 2.4           | 75           | 130          |
| 24   | Arbok      | 1767         | 21.3       | 23.5       | 25.7       | 2.2           | 60           | 106          |
| 67   | Machoke    | 1760         | 21.2       | 23.4       | 25.6       | 1.7           | 80           | 138          |
| 47   | Parasect   | 1747         | 21         | 23.2       | 25.4       | 2             | 60           | 106          |
| 148  | Dragonair  | 1747         | 21         | 23.2       | 25.4       | 1.8           | 61           | 108          |
| 22   | Fearow     | 1746         | 21         | 23.2       | 25.4       | 2.7           | 65           | 114          |
| 114  | Tangela    | 1739         | 21         | 23.1       | 25.3       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 70   | Weepinbell | 1723         | 20.7       | 22.8       | 25.1       | 1.6           | 65           | 114          |
| 124  | Jynx       | 1716         | 20.6       | 22.8       | 25         |               | 65           | 114          |
| 117  | Seadra     | 1713         | 20.6       | 22.7       | 24.9       | 2.3           | 55           | 98           |
| 137  | Porygon    | 1691         | 20.3       | 22.4       | 24.6       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 44   | Gloom      | 1689         | 20.3       | 22.4       | 24.6       | 1.5           | 60           | 106          |
| 105  | Marowak    | 1656         | 19.8       | 21.9       | 24.1       | 1.7           | 60           | 106          |
| 101  | Electrode  | 1646         | 19.7       | 21.8       | 24         | 2             | 60           | 106          |
| 2    | Ivysaur    | 1632         | 19.5       | 21.6       | 23.8       | 1.6           | 60           | 106          |
| 53   | Persian    | 1631         | 19.5       | 21.6       | 23.7       | 2.3           | 65           | 114          |
| 108  | Lickitung  | 1626         | 19.4       | 21.5       | 23.7       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 8    | Wartortle  | 1582         | 18.9       | 20.9       | 23         | 1.6           | 59           | 105          |
| 5    | Charmeleon | 1557         | 18.5       | 20.5       | 22.7       | 1.7           | 58           | 103          |
| 77   | Ponyta     | 1516         | 17.9       | 20         | 22.1       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 107  | Hitmonchan | 1516         | 17.9       | 19.9       | 22.1       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 122  | Mr. Mime   | 1494         | 17.5       | 19.6       | 21.7       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 106  | Hitmonlee  | 1492         | 17.6       | 19.6       | 21.7       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 12   | Butterfree | 1454         | 17.2       | 19.1       | 21.2       | 3.3           | 60           | 106          |
| 20   | Raticate   | 1444         | 17         | 19         | 21         | 2.6           | 55           | 98           |
| 15   | Beedrill   | 1439         | 17         | 18.9       | 21         | 3.2           | 65           | 114          |
| 75   | Graveler   | 1433         | 16.9       | 18.8       | 20.9       | 1.7           | 55           | 98           |
| 30   | Nidorina   | 1404         | 16.6       | 18.4       | 20.4       | 1.6           | 70           | 122          |
| 93   | Haunter    | 1380         | 16.1       | 18         | 20.1       | 1.8           | 45           | 82           |
| 33   | Nidorino   | 1372         | 16.1       | 18         | 20         | 1.7           | 61           | 108          |
| 61   | Poliwhirl  | 1340         | 15.7       | 17.6       | 19.5       | 1.7           | 65           | 114          |
| 58   | Growlithe  | 1335         | 15.6       | 17.5       | 19.4       |               | 55           | 98           |
| 88   | Grimer     | 1284         | 15         | 16.8       | 18.7       |               | 80           | 138          |
| 83   | Farfetch'd | 1263         | 14.7       | 16.5       | 18.4       |               | 52           | 94           |
| 17   | Pidgeotto  | 1223         | 14.2       | 16         | 17.8       | 1.9           | 63           | 111          |
| 79   | Slowpoke   | 1218         | 14.1       | 15.9       | 17.7       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 35   | Clefairy   | 1200         | 13.9       | 15.6       | 17.5       |               | 70           | 122          |
| 111  | Rhyhorn    | 1182         | 13.6       | 15.4       | 17.2       |               | 80           | 138          |
| 51   | Dugtrio    | 1168         | 13.3       | 15.1       | 17         | 2.8           | 35           | 67           |
| 109  | Koffing    | 1151         | 13.2       | 14.9       | 16.8       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 43   | Oddish     | 1148         | 13.2       | 14.9       | 16.7       |               | 45           | 82           |
| 64   | Kadabra    | 1131         | 12.9       | 14.6       | 16.5       | 2             | 40           | 75           |
| 138  | Omanyte    | 1119         | 12.7       | 14.4       | 16.3       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 69   | Bellsprout | 1117         | 12.7       | 14.4       | 16.3       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 54   | Psyduck    | 1109         | 12.7       | 14.4       | 16.1       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 86   | Seel       | 1107         | 12.7       | 14.3       | 16.1       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 140  | Kabuto     | 1104         | 12.4       | 14.2       | 16.1       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 102  | Exeggcute  | 1099         | 12.6       | 14.2       | 16         |               | 60           | 106          |
| 66   | Machop     | 1089         | 12.4       | 14.1       | 15.9       |               | 70           | 122          |
| 133  | Eevee      | 1077         | 12.3       | 13.9       | 15.7       |               | 55           | 98           |
| 96   | Drowzee    | 1075         | 12.3       | 13.9       | 15.6       |               | 60           | 106          |
| 1    | Bulbasaur  | 1071         | 12.2       | 13.8       | 15.6       |               | 45           | 82           |
| 48   | Venonat    | 1029         | 11.7       | 13.3       | 15         |               | 60           | 106          |
| 7    | Squirtle   | 1008         | 11.4       | 13         | 14.7       |               | 44           | 81           |
| 104  | Cubone     | 1006         | 11.4       | 13         | 14.7       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 147  | Dratini    | 983          | 11.1       | 12.6       | 14.3       |               | 41           | 76           |
| 118  | Goldeen    | 965          | 10.8       | 12.4       | 14         |               | 45           | 82           |
| 4    | Charmander | 955          | 10.7       | 12.2       | 13.9       |               | 39           | 73           |
| 120  | Staryu     | 937          | 10.4       | 12         | 13.6       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 132  | Ditto      | 919          | 10.3       | 11.8       | 13.4       |               | 48           | 87           |
| 39   | Jigglypuff | 917          | 9.9        | 11.6       | 13.4       |               | 115          | 193          |
| 46   | Paras      | 916          | 10.2       | 11.7       | 13.3       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 72   | Tentacool  | 905          | 10.1       | 11.6       | 13.2       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 81   | Magnemite  | 890          | 9.7        | 11.3       | 13         |               | 25           | 51           |
| 25   | Pikachu    | 887          | 9.8        | 11.3       | 12.9       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 56   | Mankey     | 878          | 9.7        | 11.2       | 12.8       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 29   | Nidoran ?  | 876          | 9.7        | 11.2       | 12.7       |               | 55           | 98           |
| 95   | Onix       | 857          | 9.3        | 10.9       | 12.5       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 84   | Doduo      | 855          | 9.4        | 10.9       | 12.4       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 74   | Geodude    | 849          | 9.4        | 10.8       | 12.4       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 32   | Nidoran ?  | 843          | 9.3        | 10.7       | 12.3       |               | 46           | 84           |
| 100  | Voltorb    | 839          | 9.2        | 10.7       | 12.2       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 37   | Vulpix     | 831          | 9.1        | 10.6       | 12.1       |               | 38           | 71           |
| 23   | Ekans      | 824          | 9          | 10.5       | 12         |               | 35           | 67           |
| 90   | Shellder   | 822          | 8.9        | 10.4       | 12         |               | 30           | 59           |
| 92   | Gastly     | 804          | 8.7        | 10.1       | 11.7       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 27   | Sandshrew  | 798          | 8.7        | 10.1       | 11.6       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 60   | Poliwag    | 795          | 8.7        | 10.1       | 11.6       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 116  | Horsea     | 794          | 8.6        | 10         | 11.6       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 98   | Krabby     | 792          | 8.6        | 10         | 11.5       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 52   | Meowth     | 756          | 8.2        | 9.6        | 11         |               | 40           | 75           |
| 21   | Spearow    | 686          | 7.3        | 8.6        | 10         |               | 40           | 75           |
| 16   | Pidgey     | 679          | 7.3        | 8.5        | 9.9        |               | 40           | 75           |
| 113  | Chansey    | 675          | 6.3        | 8          | 9.8        |               | 250          | 407          |
| 41   | Zubat      | 642          | 6.8        | 8          | 9.4        |               | 40           | 75           |
| 63   | Abra       | 600          | 6.2        | 7.4        | 8.7        |               | 25           | 51           |
| 19   | Rattata    | 581          | 6          | 7.2        | 8.5        |               | 30           | 59           |
| 14   | Kakuna     | 485          | 4.8        | 5.9        | 7.1        | 1.1           | 45           | 82           |
| 11   | Metapod    | 477          | 4.7        | 5.8        | 7          | 1.1           | 50           | 90           |
| 50   | Diglett    | 456          | 4.1        | 5.3        | 6.6        |               | 10           | 27           |
| 13   | Weedle     | 449          | 4.4        | 5.4        | 6.5        |               | 40           | 75           |
| 10   | Caterpie   | 443          | 4.3        | 5.3        | 6.5        |               | 45           | 82           |
| 129  | Magikarp   | 262          | 2.2        | 3          | 3.8        |               | 20           | 43           |
```

---

- [Source Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZ1daunztOgvOZxO7ABfJPF41-2mqMDzY1Qs_0OWwq8) spreadsheet from reddit TheSilphRoad
- [External Link to rankboost.com](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/tier-list/) with orignal tier info, speed of attacks and some other tid-bits.

Comment: how does it come that I have 2 pokemon of the same kind both maxed their CP bar but having diferent CP value if the table is correct?

Comment: @Zaibis depending on the CP when it is caught in the wild, a Pokemon can have higher or lower max CP.

Comment: I find it kind of lame that Vaporeon and other Eeveelutions are so high up the list when they're so easy to acquire.

Answer (score 5):

The more CP a pokemon gains per level up should have a higher CP cap. Here is a partial CP tier list: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4se870/pokemon_cp_tier_list/

I believe the reason for this is because all pokemon gain the same percentage of max CP per power up so by this logic the more CP a pokemon gains per power up should have a higher max CP.